# How can I configure a new session on gnome centos 7 to run only my qml interface?

Tags: qt, qml, centos7, gnome-shell, gnome-3

I want to create a new session on gnome that only shows to the user my qml interface, and the user cant opens the terminal or do anything that is not by my qml interface, I tried this script, that set to enable my services that run my qml interface, and after this, I reboot the machine.

I tried this in /usr/share/session/xsessions :

I created a new .desktop file

the test is my script .sh that set to enable my services

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=test
Comment=Test
Icon=utilities-terminal
Exec=test
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

After I created this file I renamed it as gnome-classic.desktop, to the system run it by default, but when I reboot my machine my screen got black, and my qml interface didn't show.

I already tested my services before do this, so my services are ok, the problem is the session.

How can I do this?

Comment: May be you want [Boot to Qt](https://doc.qt.io/QtForDeviceCreation/qtb2-index.html)?

Comment: No, I want to create a new session, like gnome-classic but this session only run my Qt interface, and in this session the user only can use my qt interface

Comment: Do you know how can I do this?